# Facebook: how to retrieve daily email maximum amount through facebook platform

Tags: email, facebook-graph-api, facebook

i was trying to find out how many emails could an app send to a registered user through the facebook platform

I've seen the "notification.sendemail" docs and the "admin.getAllocation" docs, i even looked at the settings tabs of my facebook app developer page, but haven't been able to find the way to retrieve the total and daily email amount an app could send.

Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

That API method is deprecated according to the docs; you should ask the user for their email address ( see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ - `email` is the one you want ) and email them directly.